# How to add dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public bool IsMenuItem { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

I want to add 'CategoryId' DropDown List instead of `<here>` tag

```
 @model OnlineShopArmenia.Models.Product

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Product</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SKU" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="SKU" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="SKU" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Status" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="IsMenuItem" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsMenuItem)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Count" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Count" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Count" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
                <here>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code in your controller:

```
ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(List of categories for show in view, "Id", "Name");
```

if you have categories in your data base you can make a query for get list of categories or you can make a list of categories with Id and Name then pass the list into first parameter of SelectList.

in your View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label>Categories :</label>
      <select name="CategoryId" asp-for="CategoryId" class="formcontrol" asp-items="ViewBag.Categories">
          <option value="">Please choose user category:</option>
      </select>
      <span asp-validation-for="CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>
```

or generate it by tag helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Category ,ViewBag.Categories as SelectList,  new { @class = "form-group"} )
```

Comment: The `select` tag should represent the `CategoryId` property not `Id`.

Comment: Yes I forgot it 